# Difference(s) between Especially and Specially

Tags: adverbs

I have really hard time to figure out when to use *Specially* and when to use *Especially*. Since both are adverbs, that makes it even harder. Can anyone simply give a way to distinguish between these two adverbs?

Comment: Off topic - easily findable: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/especially-or-specially

Comment: ***Especially vs specially***: http://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/especially-specially/ . http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/especially-or-specially

Comment: We have a site search **specially** designed for quickly finding answers by typing a word or two instead of writing up an entire question. Please use the site search, **especially** since typing a word or two into a search box is much, much, much faster than writing up an entire question.